# react-rte toolbarConfig={[]} and showToolbar={false}

Tags: reactjs, rte

I'm trying to remove the toolbar from react-rte, so I tried

```
        toolbarConfig={[]},
        showToolbar={false}
```

I just want to show some html, that's all.

But it gives me this :

[image]

How can I remove toolbar in react-rte?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-water-670cg)

Comment: why not try and hide it using css by targeting the class react-rte gives the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no such option as `showToolbar`. You can set the `readOnly` option to `true`, this will prevent the rendering of the toolbar (See [RichtTextEditor.js:122](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/RichTextEditor.js#L122).). Check [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-haibt-3d43t), please note that I used `createValueFromString(...)` ([Source](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/RichTextEditor.js#L362)) for state initialization (requires the markup as string and a format option (string) ). You can adapt the format of the markup, I've used `html` for the sandbox (See available all available options [here](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/lib/EditorValue.js#L69)). Furthermore, feel free to delete `toolbarConfig` parameter, it isn't required for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

config what you want to show in the `toolbarConfig` variable, remove everything if you want.this works, just tested it.

```
const toolbarConfig = {
  display: [],
};
```

then in your JSX

```
        <RichTextEditor
          toolbarConfig={toolbarConfig}
        />
```

this works